# Remove duplicate entries in a file without sed, awk, or uniq

Tags: file, unix, duplicates

Is there a way to remove duplicate entries in a file without sed, awk, or uniq?

Comment: What's wrong with sed, awk and uniq?

Comment: [Ed man! !man ed](http://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed.msg.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Use Perl.](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch04_07.htm)

If you don't mind line numbers changing, `sort -u` (GNU systems only)

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn, I meant `perl` the UNIX utility, but fine. :)

Answer (score 2):

Even though this *is* a bit silly, it sounded fun. Here's my first attempt:

```
cat -n /etc/passwd /etc/passwd | sort -u -k 2 | sort -n | cut -b8-
```

Duplicates should be gone and the file should be in the original output order.

Comment: I haven't verified that this works, but it can be made a lot shorter; there's no need for `/tmp/passwd`.  `cat -n /etc/passwd /etc/passwd | sort ...`

Comment: Oh yes, that's much better! Thanks. :)

Comment: Thank you that was very useful :) I had an assignment and I was almost done, I just needed to format my output correctly, I just had this last part. Thank you very much :)